Getting "Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'" error when trying to run ros2 image_view node from docker container
I'm very new to ROS2 and docker. I'm wondering if someone can help me solve this problem.
I'm using a MacBook Air M1 and currently, have ROS2 running from a docker container using the Nvidia Isaac base image. I have two nodes running, an image publisher sending an image to a depth estimation ML model running in another node. That node publishes a depth map which I am trying to view using the image_view node that comes with ROS2.
Everything is running fine except when I try to run the image_view node. It throws the error "Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'" and sends me a warning, "New publisher discovered on topic '/depth', offering incompatible QoS".
I have tried multiple solutions but nothing is working.
I could be going about the problem completely wrong so if anyone has a solution or better idea for how to view the depth map I am open to all suggestions.
Thanks
